# Android 4.3 isProviderEnabled wrong result in Genymotion

Tags: android, gps, genymotion

Genymotion always said that "GPS open".(Version : 4.3).But GPS is inactive.

But my phones (not emulator) android 6,and 5 return true result.

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "GPS open", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "GPS closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose the GPS position of a Genymotion emulator thanks to the GPS widget on the right side of the screen.

Genymotion does not plug the GPS position to your computer's position.

> Pro tip: GPS,bluetooth function is not work good with emulator,just check with real devce, If real device gives good result then you are good to go

Comment: I want know GPS is on or off. But isProviderEnabled is return wrong result.Example of my problem: Genymotion GPS is closed but isProviderEnabled return gps is opened